# Using loops within custom forms in Django

Tags: django, forms, loops

I'm creating a custom form in Django that begins with 4 different elements:

```
class InputForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateField()
    item1 = forms.CharField()
    amount1 = forms.CharField()
    category1 = forms.CharField()
```

I'd like to extend this to include any number of items, amounts, and categories.

```
    item2 = forms.CharField()
    amount2 = forms.CharField()
    category3 = forms.CharField()
    item3...
```

I tried setting up the following loop, but it didn't work. Does anyone know how to make the loop work, or know another way I can avoid typing out item2, item3, item4, etc.?

```
items = []
amounts = []
categories = []

for i in range(1,3):
    items.append('item' + str(i))
    amounts.append('amount' + str(i))
    categories.append('category' + str(i))

class InputForm(forms.Form):
    for x in items:
        x = forms.CharField()
    for y in amounts:
        y = forms.CharField()
    for z in categories:
        z = forms.CharField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for are [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/). For example:

```
class InputForm(forms.Form):
    item = forms.CharField()
    amount = forms.CharField()
    category = forms.CharField()

InputFormSet = formset_factory(InputForm)
```

Then you use the `InputFormSet` to manage the collection of forms. You can use multiple formsets if you need variable number of item, amount, and categories that aren't related to each other.